# Pandas and Regex - Proofreading Or Proofreading-Helper-Software Requested

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm struggling to know whether I got my RegEx syntax doing what I actually want it to do and don't know exactly how to proofread it in a Python-specific manner.

Could someone proofread this or help me find a place to self-proofread whether this is right for displaying rows of a Pandas DataFrame where the value of a cell under the "Name" column contains a character not among the English alphabet, digits, & a variety of common punctuation characters, or did I over/under-backslash some characters?

(My guess was that I needed to backslash the backslash and the square brackets.)

*(Note:  I know the source data will never have multi-line cell values in this column.)*

```
filtereddf = df[~df['Name'].str.match(r'^[a-zA-Z\d_\s.&+-,!@#$%^*();\\/|<>"\'?=:\[\]]+$')]
```

Also, any niftier tricks for "a variety of punctuation characters" while ensuring that of things normally considered "letters," only the English 26 a-z & A-Z are allowed?

UPDATE:

I got a recommendation for the "Python Regex syntax explainer" I needed for self-proofreading in the comments -- should've thought to ask for that as an alternative rather than just asking for proofreading help.  Sorry for the badly-worded question at first; updated.

Comment: Did you consider *testing it*? If it's just the regex you want to check, use e.g. https://regex101.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, THANK YOU -- the explanation in the upper-right-hand corner was exactly what I couldn't find on my own.  I learned through it that I actually needed to escape the "+" & the "-", etc ... this is great!  I've updated the question so that this would be an answer to it -- if you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You should just delete the question, proofreading is not on topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for non ASCII characters, try this RegEx:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]
```

in Pandas:

```
df = df[df['Name'].str.contains('[^\x00-\x7F]')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but ASCII includes characters with accents in them, which the person I'm helping sort through bad data considers "problematic."  (She's looking for anything "foreign" to the English language.)

Comment: @k.., no, it doesn't include characters above `7F` (decimal 127). I.e. it doesn't include characters with accents